# git 1.9 and yum groupinstall "Development Tools"

Tags: ubuntu, rhel, yum, git

I was reading that installing unofficial repositories in RedHat was not a good idea.
So I was trying to install [NodeJS](http://tecadmin.net/setup-node-js-on-centos-rhel-6-with-example/) on the RH Server and I saw that the git version was 1.7.1. 
Our team is using 1.9 on their local ubuntus. So I was wondering if I install [git 1.9](http://tecadmin.net/install-git-1-9-on-centos-rhel/) first (would this break/make the system unstable in any way?- also need this because I need to setup the git server afterwards)
and the do the `yum groupinstall "Development Tools"`
would this result in conflict issues of some sort?

I'm trying to be very cautious here because it's the server the entire team will be using, and don't have the option to create a snapshot to roll back in case something happens...

```
==========================================================================================================
 Package                   Arch           Version                      Repository                    Size
==========================================================================================================
Installing:
 byacc                     x86_64         1.9.20070509-7.el6           rhel-x86_64-server-6          48 k
 cscope                    x86_64         15.6-6.el6                   rhel-x86_64-server-6         136 k
 ctags                     x86_64         5.8-2.el6                    rhel-x86_64-server-6         147 k
 diffstat                  x86_64         1.51-2.el6                   rhel-x86_64-server-6          29 k
 doxygen                   x86_64         1:1.6.1-6.el6                rhel-x86_64-server-6         2.4 M
 flex                      x86_64         2.5.35-8.el6                 rhel-x86_64-server-6         286 k
 gcc-c++                   x86_64         4.4.7-4.el6                  rhel-x86_64-server-6         4.7 M
 gcc-gfortran              x86_64         4.4.7-4.el6                  rhel-x86_64-server-6         4.7 M
 git                       x86_64         1.7.1-3.el6_4.1              rhel-x86_64-server-6         4.6 M
 indent                    x86_64         2.2.10-7.el6                 rhel-x86_64-server-6         115 k
 intltool                  noarch         0.41.0-1.1.el6               rhel-x86_64-server-6          58 k
 libtool                   x86_64         2.2.6-15.5.el6               rhel-x86_64-server-6         564 k
 patchutils                x86_64         0.3.1-3.1.el6                rhel-x86_64-server-6          95 k
 rcs                       x86_64         5.7-37.el6                   rhel-x86_64-server-6         173 k
 redhat-rpm-config         noarch         9.0.3-42.el6                 rhel-x86_64-server-6          59 k
 swig                      x86_64         1.3.40-6.el6                 rhel-x86_64-server-6         1.1 M
 systemtap                 x86_64         2.3-4.el6_5                  rhel-x86_64-server-6          26 k
Installing for dependencies:
 libgfortran               x86_64         4.4.7-4.el6                  rhel-x86_64-server-6         265 k
 libstdc++-devel           x86_64         4.4.7-4.el6                  rhel-x86_64-server-6         1.6 M
 perl-Error                noarch         1:0.17015-4.el6              rhel-x86_64-server-6          29 k
 perl-Git                  noarch         1.7.1-3.el6_4.1              rhel-x86_64-server-6          28 k
 perl-XML-Parser           x86_64         2.36-7.el6                   rhel-x86_64-server-6         224 k
 systemtap-client          x86_64         2.3-4.el6_5                  rhel-x86_64-server-6         3.4 M
 systemtap-devel           x86_64         2.3-4.el6_5                  rhel-x86_64-server-6         1.4 M

Transaction Summary
==========================================================================================================
Install      24 Package(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

> would this break/make the system unstable in any way?

If you need software that is only available in a certain repo, I'd probably go with it. Just make sure you actually need it first.

The problems come into the picture when the repo's/rpms are poorly designed. This can lead to situations where `yum` will install a higher version of a particular package because it's available in the other repo under the same name but then some software from the base channel won't install anymore because it was built against an earlier version number. This can create a clusterfrack of a problem that is usually not intuitively solved or backed out from.

If you use anything other than EPEL, I would just configure the repo with `enabled=0` so that the repo is disabled in general but if you need it you can just say `yum install packageName --enablerepo=repoName`. This prevents something from that repo getting installed accidentally.

Of course, there's also the issue that base channel packages are definitionally more stable than the latest and greatest just because of the QA that's done on them and the breadth of their install base.

> So I was wondering if I install git 1.9 first [...] and the do the yum groupinstall "Development Tools" would this result in conflict issues of some sort.

Potentially, you just kind of have to see what it does. Ultimately, it's up to the repo maintainer to make sure the people using their repositories have the smoothest ride possible so it's hard to tell what you're going to get once you get away from the better known repositories.

I would do the development tools first adding a `--disablerepo=repoName` to it so that gets installed and just hope that the repo maintainer used that as their reference point when deciding how to build these RPM's. That seems like the thing that would have the best chance of success. A `groupinstall` will include more packages (directly and for dependencies) than installing a particular application from will. So if something from the base channel conflicts with the unofficial repo's RPM it should be easier to piecemeal it and remove the base channel packages.

> I'm trying to be very cautious here because it's the server the entire team will be using, and don't have the option to create a snapshot to roll back in case something happens...

If that's the case, I would carefully look over the updates list with each update and make sure they're coming from the correct repositories before you tell it to proceed with the installation.

Comment: well I have installed Development tools first and then went on to finish nodeJS installation, and  git server is next probably I'll try the upgrade first, and I'll let you know how did it all go